# Sailsjs 0.10.3 - Heroku - RedisToGo - req.session undefined

Tags: session, heroku, connect, sails.js, redistogo

When using sailsjs v0.10.3 with Redis To Go for session storage, `req.session` is always `undefined`.

It is `undefined` when I deploy both locally and to Heroku. `req.session` is correctly defined when I use the default `memory` adapter.

I created a sailsjs app:

```
sails new testapp
sails generate api test testSet testGet
```

Installed connect-redis v1.4.7:

```
npm install connect-redis@~1.4.7
```

Set the configuration in `config/session.js`:

```
adapter: 'redis',
host: 'hoki.redistogo.com',
port: 10015,
db: 'redistogo',
pass: '88819aa089d3dd86235f9fad4cb92e48'
```

Set the configuration in `config/socket.js`:

```
adapter: 'redis',
host: 'hoki.redistogo.com',
port: 10015,
db: 'redistogo',
pass: '88819aa089d3dd86235f9fad4cb92e48'
```

Created some controller actions which get and set a session value:

```
UserController.js

testSet: function (req, res) {

  req.session.testVar = "I am the test var!";

  return res.ok();
},

testGet: function (req, res) {
  return res.json({
    testVar: req.session.testVar
  });
}
```

And finally deployed to Heroku:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
heroku create
heroku addons:add redistogo
git push heroku master
git
```

This is the error:

```
error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response:  
TypeError: Cannot set property 'testVar' of undefined 
at module.exports.testSet (/app/api/controllers/TestController.js:46:25)
```

It seems like this simple example should work.

Here is a repo of the example above:

https://github.com/derekbasch/sailsjs-redistogo-testapp

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I tried using the MemoryStore adapter on Heroku to get/set a session variable. That failed with `undefined` also. It works locally. Now I am even more confused.

Comment: Having same problem here TT

Comment: I've got the same issue...

Comment: Are you able to connect to a local instance of Redis? I've had issues getting Sails to play with RedisToGo, so making sure the issue truly is RedisToGo might make things a bit easier to work with.

Comment: @CaseyWebb I do not have Redis installed locally. I have this problem with all of the cloud based providers.

Comment: Try opening a support ticket with Heroku. They may have to open the port for you.

Comment: Any updates ? I'm also facing same :(

Answer (score 1):

We are using rediscloud (sails app on heroku) and the `db` property is set to `0`. Could this be the problem?

Also, you should parse the URL provided by heroku via en env variables. This is what we use (coffeescript):

```
parseRedisUrl = ( url ) ->
  parsed = require( 'url' ).parse( url )
  password = (parsed.auth || '').split( ':' )[1]

  hostname: parsed.hostname
  port: parsed.port
  password: password

redis = parseRedisUrl( process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL || "redis://localhost:6379" )

module.exports.session =

  secret: '...'

  adapter: 'redis'
  host: redis.hostname
  port: redis.port
  pass: redis.password
  db: 0
  ttl: 60 * 60 * 24
```

Comment: And can I get the user with `parsed.user` ?